# SQL Inner join division

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, division

I have issue with my inner join division below. From my oracle, it keep prompt me missing right parenthesis when I have already close it. I'll need to get the names of the patient who have collected all items.

```
Select P.name
From ((((Select Patientid From Patient) As P
Inner Join (Select Accountno, Patientid From Account) As A1
on P.PatientID = A1.PatientID)
Inner Join (Select Accountno, Itemno From AccountType) As Al 
On A1.Accountno = Al.Accountno)
Inner Join (Select Itemno From Item) As I
On Al.Itemno = I.Itemno)
Group By Al.Itemno
Having Count(*) >= (Select Count(*) FROM AccountType);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler approach that I believe is essentially equivalent:

```
select a.name
from Patient a
inner join Account b on a.PatientID = b.PatientID
inner join AccountType c on b.Accountno = c.Accountno
inner join Item d on c.Itemno = d.Itemno
group by c.Accountno, a.name
having Count(*) >= (Select Count(*) FROM AccountType);
```

This approach is a bit simpler. It has the added benefit of being much more likely to use indexes on the tables -- if you do joins between what are essentially 'join tables' in memory, you don't get the benefit of the indexes that exist for the physical tables in memory.

I also usually alias table names using sequential letters -- 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' as you can see. I find that when I'm writing complicated queries it makes it easier for me to follow. 'a' is the first table in the join, 'b' is the second, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After trying out both of the answers provided. It prompt me 'Not a group by expression' at line 1 which is p.name. But It can't be group by p.name. There would not be any results showing. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited the query to try to address that. I believe it may work. Basically, to do the select that way the issue is likely that a.name needs to be in the group by column. Although, there may still be some issues if you're grouping by Accountno, but only selecting the name.

Comment: Same results. No rows shown. By right there should be five rows shown. When i join the tables, i didn't see any rows too. Any ideas?

Comment: It's really imposible to to say without looking at the data. If the query is correct, that means the issue is likely that there's no data that matches the query. I'd start by removing the HAVING clause and seeing if there's any data at all that matches the joins. If there's even one of the joins that has no data, the join will fail and no data will be returned.

Comment: In most cases, Oracle will inline the sub-queries and will still be able to use indexes. However, I'd still recommend this version over the OP's, simply for readability.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM patient p
       INNER JOIN account a ON (a.patientID = p.patientID)
       INNER JOIN accountType accTyp ON (accTyp.accountNo = a.accountNo)
       INNER JOIN item i ON (i.itemNo = accTyp.itemNo)
 GROUP BY accTyp.itemNo
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM accountType);
```

Note that having an alias of A1 and an alias of Al is quite confusing.  You want to pick more meaningful and more distinguishing aliases.

Comment: I have an error showing not a group by expression in line 1. which is oracle wants me to group by p.name. But it's not possible to do so. There will not be any records showing